# In VScode, How to custom the PHP heredoc tag "HTML" to others?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm using VScode + PHP Intelephense. Currently if using `HTML` as heredoc tag, it will highlight the HTML code:

```
return <<<HTML
    <input name="$name" />
    HTML;
```

But the following code is not highlighted:

```
return <<<h
    <input name="$name" />
    h;
```

So how can I get the code to be highlighted when using `h` tag?

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using h as a custom identifier,
use "html" as custom identifier this should would as vscode can now identify this as a html highlighter.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question as OP already reflected this in the question